# Android ToggleButton

Tags: android, view

By following this [article](http://ww1.mokasocial.com/) I was able to create a toggle button that's made out of images. My toggle doesnt have any text, just on/off images.

When my toggle button is created it's being stretched and loses it's proportions, how do I make it retain it's original size?

These are the images im using:

[image: on]

[image: off]

The code:

***main.xml:***

```
<ToggleButton
   android:id="@+id/changeNumerals"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:checked="true"
   android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg"
   android:textOn=""
   android:textOff=""            
/>
```

***drawable/toggle.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" />
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" />
</selector>
```

***drawable/toggle_bg.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
   <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: use wrap content for height and width  of the toggle button

Comment: wrap_content is already there...

Comment: Have you read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: are you using nine patch images ??

Comment: The images a regular PNGs without the 9patch black lines, not sure if those image can be stretched properly using 9patch because of their circular parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dimensions are "hardcoded" but they'll scale with the size of your screen.

So the xml could look like:

```
android:layout_width="64dp"
android:layout_height="24dp"
```

The official documentation for dps is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#dimension)

Answer (score 13):

Try following attributes for `<ToggleButton>`

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:button="@drawable/toggle_bg"
```

It should work. Good luck :)

Comment: this puts the image on top of the button in it's correct size but the background of the toggle is the stretched toggle images. I tried removing android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg" which removed the image and brought back the regular toggle button with my toggle images on top of it.

Comment: how i add this propert programaticlly? android:button="@drawable/toggle_bg"

Comment: You can use either of these setButtonDrawable(int resid) setButtonDrawable(Drawable d)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonDrawable(int)

Comment: THANK YOU!!! My toggle button looked funky next to my other image buttons because of the hard coded size and this solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 3):

To support versions from GINGERBREAD up to the current ones, I ended up using:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/filterPhotos"
    android:checked="true"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/toggle_filter_photos"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

and the drawable toggle_filter_photos.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/picture_filter_icons"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/picture_inactive_filter_icons" />
</selector>
```

The other solutions above didn't work well for GINGERBREAD and newer as either the icons wouldn't show up at all (with `android:button` on GINGERBREAD) or the aspect ratio was lost (with `android:background` on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 (4.2.2)).

Comment: comment at last work for me "android:button on GINGERBREAD" ..thanks