# How to create this Toggle via code or XML in Android?

Tags: android

I have these images

[image]
[image]

and I use them in code like so:

```
<style name="SettingsToggleButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toggle_selector</item>
    <item name="android:checked">false</item>
    <item name="android:text">""</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">""</item>
    <item name="android:textOn">""</item>
</style>

<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/swUseMobileNetwork"
            style="@style/SettingsToggleButtonStyle"/>
```

When I look at my activity they are hideous. Pixelized and with white artifacts in the round parts outline.

[image]

How can I create the same effect but with XML or Code and not using images?

Answer (score 1):

Simple thing is that you are not aware of the new android toggle which really awesome, now i also avoid the use of these images concept which don't have any animation:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/toggle"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff=""
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                android:textOn=""
                android:button="@null"


  />
```

add this dependencies to you build.gradle to add android Api 23  support libs :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Check liks for your problem:
https://androidician.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/android-custom-toggle-button-example-ios-like-toggle-buttons/

[Android ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621019/android-togglebutton)

Comment: looks good but I have design specifications which require that particular implementation that I showed. I will talk to the designers to let me use the native view if I dont find a way to create it programmatically

Comment: your code seems well, but check the links in my answer that may help you.

Comment: that link is where I got this button from actually. And I think it's where designers got the idea from as well :)